# Is there a software to measure the FLOPS and Raw Time of a C++ program?

Tags: c++, performance-analysis

I am running a C++ code which contains a Matrix multiplication of 2048 X 2048 matrices. Is there a library or a package or a software which can give me the Raw time and FLOPs for my program?

Comment: What is "raw time" for you? CPU time?

Comment: Yes it is CPU time

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you could use the [time(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) and [perf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) command and use related functions documented in [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), in particular [clock_gettime(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).

The [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) open source software uses these.

With a recent C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) use also [`<chrono>` defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) functions.

My opinion is that on most dekstop, server, or laptop computers in 2022, the [FLOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) is not very significant or meaningful. What about [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) and [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units)s?

Contact me by email at `basile@starynkevitch.net` (near Paris in France) for more details.